# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.xsp.extlib.util.ExtLibUtil

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-extlib

Last week I was playing with sessionScope values being read and written from java code that was called from on beforePageLoad in an XPage.  It was working when called on the server, but this week after rebooting the server it is now giving an error.  The Java code still compiles.

To resolve the extlib in Designer I include the JAR "com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core_11.0.1.v00_00_20200319-1021.jar"
as an external JAR.

If I run "tell http osgi ss com.ibm.xsp.extlib" on the console I get:
[image]

The lines I am using in Java are:
import com.ibm.xsp.extlib.util.ExtLibUtil;

and

Map<String, Object> sessionScope = ExtLibUtil.getSessionScope();

Am I including the wrong JAR file? I can't understand why it worked Friday, but today isn't working.

Comment: The class com.ibm.xsp.extlib.util.ExtLibUtil is part of the server and it is not necessary to include the jar. So something else is wrong. Can you show us the full stack trace? Have you tried restarting Domino?

Comment: Thanks Per, your answer helped me.  By indicating that it wasn't necessary to include the jar it got me to thinking, well how else would it know I needed the Jar when compiling the Java code.   The key setting was under the XSP Configuration, Page Generation Tab.  I hadn't checked the box for extended XPage controls to use.  Checking the box for com.ibm.xsp.extlib.library , resolved my issue.  Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including the Jar is not necessary.  Under XSP Configuration, Page Generation Tab, the extended XPage controls to use checkbox for com.ibm.xsp.extlib.library needs to be checked. This resolved the issue, and removed compilation errors too.
[image]